# Separate authentication server for users and APIs

Tags: api, security, authentication

I'm working on a cloud service authentication system and I'm not entirely sure what the optimal way to handle authenticating requests is. We're planning to run our image server as a separate process from our API server so that we can scale them independently of each other. Handling request authentication with API keys is fairly simple, because we can just have the image server store its own API key and check that requests provide it in a header (over HTTPS obviously), same with the API server. For users though it gets more complex.

Right now we have it setup so that the API server will handle generating a session token and storing users in its database, however what we'd like to do is use 3 servers:

- authentication server
- API server
- image server

and have the image and API servers authenticate requests against the authentication server. How exactly should this be done though? It seems like a bad idea performance-wise to hit the authentication server for every request that the API and image servers make. Can/should a token be verified from a different server than it was created on?

So for example: can/should I pass the token received from the authentication server to the image server, verify that the token came from "my.auth.server" and check that the user ID is the right one? Would JWTs be a good type of token for this?

Answer (score 13):

Here's an alternative approach.

Your authentication issues a JWT token that is signed using a secret **that is also available in your API and server images**. The reason they need to be there too is that you will need to verify the tokens received to make sure you created them. The nice thing about JWTs is that their payload can hold claims as to what the user is **authorised to access** should different users have different access control levels.

That architecture renders authentication stateless: No need to store any tokens in a database unless you would like to handle token blacklisting (think banning users). Being stateless is crucial if you ever need to scale. That also frees up your API and image servers from having to call the authentication server at all as all the information they need for both authentication and authorisation are in the issued token.

Flow (no refresh tokens):

1. User authenticates with the authentication server (eg: POST /auth/login) and receives a JWT token generated and signed by the auth server.
2. User uses that token to talk to your API and image servers and assuming user is authorised), gets and posts the necessary resources.

There are a couple of issues here. Namely, that auth token in the wrong hands provides unlimited access to a malicious user to pretend they are the affected user and call your APIs indefinitely. To handle that, tokens have an expiry date and clients are forced to request new tokens whenever expiry happens. That expiry is part of the token's payload. But if tokens are short-lived, do we require users to authenticate with their usernames and password every time? No. We do not want to ask a user for their password every 30min to an hour, and we do not want to persist that password anywhere in the client. To get around that issue, we introduce the concept of **refresh tokens**. They are longer lived tokens that serve one purpose: act as a user's password, authenticate them to get a new token. Downside is that with this architecture your authentication server needs to persist these refresh token in a database **to make them revokable before they expire (think "revoked" column in tokens table)**.

New flow (with refresh tokens):

1. User authenticates with the authentication server (eg: POST /auth/login) and receives a JWT token generated and signed by the auth server, **alongside a long lived (eg: 6 months) refresh token that they store securely**
2. Whenever the user needs to make an API request, the token's expiry is checked. Assuming it has not yet expired, user uses that token to talk to your API and image servers and assuming user is authorised), gets and posts the necessary resources.
3. If the token has indeed expired, there is a need to refresh your token, user calls authentication server (EG: POST / auth/token) and passes the securely stored refresh token. Response is a new access token issued.
4. Use that new token to talk to your API image servers.

**OPTIONAL (banning users)**

How do we ban users? Using that model there is no easy way to do so. Enhancement: Every persisted refresh token includes a **blacklisted** field and only issue new tokens if the refresh token isn't black listed.

**Things to consider:**

- You may want to rotate refresh token. To do so, blacklist the refresh token each time your user needs a new access token. That way refresh tokens can only be used once. Downside you will end up with a lot more refresh tokens but that can easily be solved with a job that clears blacklisted refresh tokens (eg: once a day)
- You may want to consider setting a maximum number of allowed refresh tokens issued per user (say 10 or 20) as you issue a new one every time they login (with username and password). This number depends on your flow, how many clients a user may use (web, mobile, etc) and other factors.
- You can store some additional metadata (ip, geolocation, device, browser cookie, etc.) alongside refresh tokens. That way, you can be smart about when to reject malicious usages of refresh tokens in case it's compromised.
- **Common Q: Why store all refresh tokens, and not just revoked ones?** You *could* do that. Ask yourself the following: Will I, at any point, need to have a functionality where I can dynamically revoke valid refresh tokens, based on some arbitrary, regulatory, legal, integrity, security etc. criteria? If so, the least you will need is a list of all issued tokens, plus any data required to implement the criterion logic. Example: Due to regulation, I need to ban all EU users equates to a `delete from refresh_tokens were user_ip in <... eu logic ...>`

Answer (score 0):

one of the best ways to use is a JWT Token , you can generate and share it between all your servers and validate it on the server side .

https://jwt.io

also I think the best architecture to use in this case is the micro service architecture